# How to Generate Random String using Laravel Faker?

Tags: laravel, faker, fake-repositories

is there any way or method to generate fake string using laravel faker ?

like in laravel we generate string upto 20 chars..

```
 str_random(20);
```

Answer (score 73):

Faker offers a couple of methods that let you replace placeholders in a given string with random characters:

- **lexify** - takes given string and replaces ? with random letters
- **asciify** - takes given string and replaces * with random ascii characters
- **numerify** - takes given string and replaces # with random digits
- **bothify** - combines the lexify and numerify

You could try to use one of them, depending on the requirements you have for that random string you need. **asciify** uses the largest set of characters as replacement so using that one makes most sense.

The following will give you a **random string of 20 ascii characters**:

```
$faker->asciify('********************')
```

Comment: you can produce a string with 20 times a * with str_repeat('*', 20)

Answer (score 71):

Alternate for generate string without special chars.

```
$faker->regexify('[A-Za-z0-9]{20}')
```

Comment: You can use like [A-z] to simplify the [A-Za-z] in your regex.

Comment: @francisco these are not the same. A-z is a character range of ascii 65 to 122. You should use /[A-Za-z]/ or /[a-z]/i, unless you wish to include these characters: [ \ ] ^ _ `

Answer (score 5):

```
$faker->text()
// generates 50 char by default: "Aut quo omnis placeat eos omnis eos."

$faker->text(10);
// generates 10 char by default: "Labore."
```

All texts seems to be one or more latin pseudo-sentences with spaces and always a dot in the end (of each sentence).

Answer (score 4):

```
$faker->text($maxNbChars = 50);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: $faker->text(50);

Comment: This is wrong, it makes a sentence with spaces in the middle of words.

Answer (score 2):

uze **Faker\Provider\en_US\Text**

```
<?php

realText($maxNbChars = 200, $indexSize = 2) // "And yet I wish you could manage it?) 'And what are they made of?' Alice asked in a shrill, passionate voice. 'Would YOU like cats if you were never even spoke to Time!' 'Perhaps not,' Alice replied."
```